# Ionic2 Ion-Input onSubmit clicks top button inside a form

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic2

I have a form which contains an ion-button and an ion-input.

The ion-button is not used for form-submission. If i want to edit a value inside the input and press okay i expect the keyboard to hide, but the ion-button reacts on this event and opens his onClick action.

you can find a Demo for this in this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JCVXk6trEmKUrwZznBAX?p=preview) (home.html/ts) and can reproduce it when pressing enter inside the input element. I simply want to avoid the gotoSelectedView function to be triggered.

```
       <form [ngFormModel]="form">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
                    <ion-input ngControl="username" type="text"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
                    <ion-input ngControl="password" type="password"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                  <button ion-item  (click)="gotoSelectView()">
                      <ion-label >SelectItem</ion-label>
                      <ion-note item-right>SelectedValue</ion-note>
                  </button>
            </ion-list>
        </form>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: do you have any code snippet showing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it with adding a listener on the form for `keydown.enter`
in main.html:

```
 <form [ngFormModel]="form" (keydown.enter)="hideKeyboard($event)">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
                <ion-input ngControl="username" type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
                <ion-input ngControl="password" type="password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
              <button ion-item  (click)="gotoSelectView()">
                  <ion-label >SelectItem</ion-label>
                  <ion-note item-right>SelectedValue</ion-note>
              </button>
        </ion-list>
    </form>
```

in main.ts:

```
  hideKeyboard(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Keyboard.close();
  }
```